# MySQL string returning error

Tags: php, mysql, string

```
 "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$file_location." INTO TABLE p4p.users_csv_import
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' STARTING BY ''
 IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

Not sure what is incorrect, but it is with my single/double quotes.

Error Number: 1064

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'assets/temp/p4p57.csv INTO TABLE p4p.users_csv_import FIELDS TERMINATED ' at line 1

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE assets/temp/p4p57.csv INTO TABLE p4p.users_csv_import FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY '' IGNORE 1 LINES

Filename: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/models/user_import_model.php

Line Number: 28
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? What is the value of `$file_location`? Can you should us what the string looks like with the variable interpolated?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: '' looks like an empty string, are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: The actual error message and an echo of the actual statement submitted would both be useful.

Comment: Is `$file_location` quoted?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `$file_location` in single quotes.

Edit - specifically:

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_location."' INTO TABLE business.table
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' STARTING BY ''
 IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are not providing an error, my gut tells me the issue is with the `\n` which should probably be a `\\n`.  So try this instead.

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$file_location." INTO TABLE business.table
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' STARTING BY ''
 IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

Comment: I edited to account for your correction, which was right but still missing something. I am so bad with these strings :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '.$file_location.' INTO TABLE business.table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
    IGNORE 1 LINES";

and share your result should it worked for you or not?